# A question about super-harmonic functions

Tags: harmonic-analysis, harmonic-functions

Lets call a function $f : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ to be super-harmonic if $\nabla ^2 f = \sum_{i=1}^n \partial_i^2 f  \leq 0$.

Now given such a $f$ as above I want to consider the following subset of harmonic functions,

$$\left \{ g : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \mid  \nabla ^2 g =0 ~\& ~\langle \nabla f , \nabla g \rangle = 0 \right \} $$

- Is this set a thing that has been studied? Any ideas on what can be said about this set like when is it non-trivial?

Comment: You can write $f$ as a sum of a harmonic function $f_1$ and a Newtonian potential $f_2$. My guess would be that if $f_1$ is non-zero, then there is no such non-zero $g$, while if $f_1$ is zero, then the condition on $g$ reads: $g$ is a harmonic function orthogonal to the measure $\Delta f$. But this is merely a guess, I did not think about it carefully.

Comment: What do you mean by a Newtonian Potential? I think a candidate $f$ is $\Vert x \Vert^4$, right?

Comment: Newtonian potential is the convolution of a measure with the Newtonian kernel $c_n |x|^{2-n}$, as in [Riesz's theorem](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Riesz_theorem(2)). However, I had in mind more regular examples than $f = |x|^4$; for this $f$ I doubt there is any such $g$, is there?

Comment: Oh, I realise that I understood $\langle \nabla f, \nabla g\rangle$ as the *integral* of the dot product, while apparently this was meant to simply mean the dot product. Sorry.

Comment: So what is your current conclusion? :D Are there any super-harmonic functions which are lowerbounded? What regular examples did you have in mind?

Comment: I do not think I have any conclusion now. The "regular" examples I had in mind are such that $|\nabla f| \times |\nabla g|$ are integrable, but as I said, I misunderstood the question. Finally, any Newtonian potential of a compactly supported nonnegative function is superharmonic and bounded.

Comment: Thanks! Can we get lowerbounded super-harmonic functions?

Comment: Yes, as written above: convolve any non-negative continuous, compactly supported function with the Newtonian kernel. To give a specific example: if I remember correctly, $(1+|x|^2)^{1-n/2}$ has Laplacian equal to $c_n (1 + |x|^2)^{-1-n/2}$.

Comment: This lapalcian you write is not negative. Then how is this super-harmonic?

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Laplacian+1%2F%281%2Bx%5E2%29%5E%281%2F2%29

This is not super-harmonic at $n=1$

Comment: Well, I meant $n \geqslant 3$. And, of course, I forgot the minus sign (that is, the way it is written, $c_n = -n(n-2)$ is negative).

Comment: My linked wolfram alpha code computes the Laplacian for $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$. This is actually the $n=3$ case, right? And then we have $\nabla^2 \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}} = \frac{2x^2 -1}{(1+x^2)^{2.5}}$.So I am not seeing how this is super-harmonic.

Comment: I guess [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Laplacian+1%2F%281%2Bx%5E2%2By%5E2%2Bz%5E2%29%5E%281%2F2%29) is a correct WA query for 3-D case, is it not?